# How to switch between grid layouts DRY without using separate application layout files?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, flexbox

I'm redesigning a new Rails Webapplication and created a 2- and 3-column layout with CSS Grid (because of some pages should have 2 and other 3 columns):

My CSS:

```
  .container-3-col {
    display: grid;

    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header"
      "nav content side"
      "footer footer footer";

    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr 250px;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;

    height: 100vh;
  }
  .container-2-col {
    display: grid;

    grid-template-areas:
      "header header"
      "nav content"
      "footer footer";

    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;

    height: 100vh;
  }
```

I came up with this HTML (ERB-) Body:

```
<body>

  <% if defined? @no_side_menu %>
    <!-- Grid Layout 2 columns-->
    <div class="container-2-col">
      <header>
      </header>
      <nav>
      </nav>
      <main>
      </main>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <!-- Grid Layout 3 columns-->
    <div class="container-3-col">
      <header>
      </header>
      <nav>
      </nav>
      <main>
      </main>
      <aside>
        side menu column
      </aside>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  <% end %>

</body>
```

I'd like to extract the HTML-Elements header, nav and footer outside of the if-conditional but this is conflicting with the `container-3-col` and `container-2-col` div. Is there another way to make this more DRY?

Answer (score 0):

after thinking about it a bit longer, I came to the following solution without changing the CSS:

```
<div class="<%= @no_side_menu ? 'container-2-col' : 'container-3-col' %>">
  <header>
    Header content
  </header>

  <nav>
    <%= render partial: 'spree/shared/taxonomies' %>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <%= yield %>
  </main>

  <% unless @no_side_menu %>
    <aside>
    </aside>
  <% end %>

  <footer>
    <%= render partial: 'spree/shared/footer' %>
  </footer>
</div>
```

If someone has a better solution please feel free to post it here.